# Get Longitude and Latitude values from Google Geocoding API in Android Studio with Java

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

This is my getCurrentLocation Method:

```
private CurrentLocation getCurrentLocation(String jsonData) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonData);
    JSONArray results = object.getJSONArray("results");

    JSONObject objects = results.getJSONObject(0);
    JSONObject geometry = objects.getJSONObject("geometry");
    JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
    //instance of CurrentLocation class
    CurrentLocation currentLocation = new CurrentLocation();
    currentLocation.setLongitude(location.getDouble("lat"));
    currentLocation.setLatitude(location.getDouble("lng")); 
    Log.i(TAG, "FROM JSON: " + currentLocation.getLatitude());
    Log.i(TAG, "FROM JSON: " + currentLocation.getLongitude());
return currentLocation;
}
```

prints out FROM JSON: -117.9145036
FROM JSON: 33.8352932 which is correct,

I get an error of NullPointerException on the line:

```
 private void updateLocation() {
       getForecast(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
}
```

I know that private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) works because i have put in two doubles as parameters and it works. 
I am still pretty new to android and i know there is a geolocator in the studio itself but I would like to do it from the API. I am not sure what the nullException is pointing to and any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here are my other methods if it helps:
Oncreate:

```
This is my Oncreate method:

public void onClick(View view) {
             String name = mNameField.getText().toString();
             getLocation(name);
             updateLocation(); // error here?
```

and getLocation:

```
public void getLocation(String name) {
    //get Google api
    String geoLocatingUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+name+"&key=AIzaSyAsJJIEeB952KpjpoFoMuYHd6gev85uzYs";

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(geoLocatingUrl)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        //UI thread executes enqueue, sends to OKHttp Library gets data, response or failure back to UI
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {

            }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {

            try {
                   String jsonData = response.body().string();
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                    mCurrentLocation = getCurrentLocation(jsonData);
                    Log.v(TAG, jsonData);

                } else {
                    alertUserAboutError();

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception caught: ", e);

            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and getForecast:

```
private void getForecast(double latitude, double longitude) {
    String apiKey = "//myapikey";

    String forecastUrl =  "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/" + apiKey +
            "/" + latitude + "," + longitude;

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) { //runs if network is there and available
        toggleRefresh();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(forecastUrl)
                .build();

        Call call = client.newCall(request);
        //UI thread executes enqueue, sends to OKHttp Library gets data, response or failure back to UI
        call.enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Request request, IOException e) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleRefresh();
                    }
                });
                alertUserAboutError();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        toggleRefresh();
                    }
                });
                try {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                        mCurrentWeather = getCurrentDetails(jsonData);
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                updateDisplay();
                            }
                        });

                    } else {
                        alertUserAboutError();
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.
                        network_unavailable_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are printing the whole object, try printing specific data like currentLocation.getLatitude() for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I am assuming that you are trying to print the object of the class "CurrentLocation". So the value is @42c49c78.What you have to do is like

```
 Log.i(TAG, "FROM JSON: " + currentLocation.getLatitude());
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes that part prints out the latitude. I am trying to figure out why it is printing out a nullpointerException on the updateLocation method thank you for your help (:

Comment: You have to post your getForecast() method. It's difficult to answer without it.

Comment: i posted that but if it works doesn't that mean the problem is elsewhere? if i do getForecast(33.15351, -127.251521) it displays the weather with whatever city that is

Comment: Please post the full logcat. Means it is necessary to find out for which line it is causing null pointer exception.

Comment: getForecast(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());               that line

Comment: No you are getting wrong.You have to find out it is showing null pointer exception in which line number of the method  getForecast().If it is possible try to debug your application.Put a break pointer inside your method.

Comment: it says mCurrentLocation = null

Comment: So that means you haven't initialized the object before you execute your method . I mean to say that you have do this  CurrentLocation mCurrentLocation=new CurrentLocation().After that you can call mCurrentLocation.getLatitude().Did you get it?

Comment: i placed this in my updateLocation method?  and when i press the onClick button it is getting two values randomly regardless of the city i type in..

Comment: Now the problem of random generating can be solved if just post all your source code.Or you have to debug your whole app and try to find out the problem.

Comment: Hahaha. You have to learn core java first then android.You are very weak in java.If you desperately need help then I can help you On Saturday. But it's better if you can solve out the problem.

Comment: Yeah I know lol I'm going to finish the java course on teamtreehouse right now I actually didn't expect to get this far at all when i barely know java.

Comment: i already have the constructor  CurrentLocation currentLocation = new CurrentLocation(); in my first getCurrentLocation Method, so i can't have two constructors in the same class without changing something else right

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT THANKS. i took out the updateLocation method competely and placed the getForecast inside of the getLocation method and used another runONUIThread. thank you!!!!

Comment: Nice.Glad to help you